# Am I able to set up a way to use all 4 pairs in my ethernet cable without gigabit support?

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, modem

I live in an apartment above a store that provides my internet connection. Downstairs in the store there is a router which I'm fairly sure does not support gigabit internet. The wifi is atrociously slow, however I aim to fix this by connecting a cable to the modem directly to my computer. It should be noted that we receive 100 mbps on speedtest

I've delved a bit into how ethernet cables work and noticed that non-gigabit internet only uses two pairs. This brings me to my first question:

**Is there a way to make it use two pairs for the router and the other two pairs to my computer, so that both get their individual 100 mbps?**

I was also looking into splitters, but I'm not sure if they work the way I think they do. I've thought about using two tiny cables from the modem downstairs, use a splitter to get a single output, hook that up the existing cable upstairs, then split it off again using one ethernet cable on my PC and the other on the router. I realize that the purpose of a router is routing the internet off so I could just stick my PC's ethernet cable in there instead, but that would mean wifi and cabled internet have to share the 100mbps, (which is something that I'm trying to prevent).

It should be noted that the modem downstairs does not use any of the modem output ports.

Any help is greatly appreciated! If any additional information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Speed is determined by the ISP (furnisher), not by the cable.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to be able to modify BOTH ends of a L2 connection (like your ethernet) if you want to change anything about how the wires are used.

Comment: Figured, I discovered yesterday that the ISP only delivers 100mbps to the store anyway so it won't matter to set it up like this. Thanks for the responses though!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, nope... There is no reason for a router to cut you off on 100mbit, so it is more likely that either, the internet itself has a maximum of 100mbit, or the router cannot do more than 100mbit. For example older routers may not have a strong enough cpu inside to direct more than 100mbit of traffic, so it will be limited to that amount regardless of what ports are capable off and what speeds the internet is having.

Then again, Wifi itself may also reaching its limit, so using a cable is definitely better, but the router may need to be replaced too. There is no way to split it, nor is this necessary. Maximum speeds will always be tried to reached, so no need to pull any fancy trickery here, unless the owner of the store is deliberately capping you, in which case, it doesn't matter what you do, they'll stop you anyway.